# Android SqLite Exception: unrecognized token in deleting from database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to delete everything from my database called Globals which contains a list of sessionID's. A SessionID is generated each time a user logs in and therefore previous sessionID's are not needed within the database and must be deleted since they will never be in use again. I implemented a method to delete all sessionID's within the database except for the  one specified but I get this error when I run my code:

> "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "8a8878dc" (code 1): , while compiling"

How do I fix this?

This is my delete method for removing the sessionID's

```
public void deleteAll(String sessionID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_SESSIONSTATE, KEY_SESSIONID + " != " + sessionID , null);
}
```

and it is run in this code:
The result object  returns a string which gives the sessionID I want to use

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                if(result != null)
                {
                    globals = new Globals(getBaseContext());

                    String resultStr = result.getPropertyAsString(0);
                    resultStr = resultStr.replace("\n", "");
                    String [] resultArr = resultStr.split("\\^");
                    sessionID = resultArr[0];
                    globals.deleteAll(sessionID);
                }
```

Comment: `8a8878dc-7f5d-43c8-a88b-60a23831b9f3` is a string. Use it like a string `'8a8878dc-7f5d-43c8-a88b-60a23831b9f3'`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, strings must be written 'in quotes'.

However, to avoid formatting problems like this, you should use parameters:

```java
db.delete(TABLE_SESSIONSTATE,
          KEY_SESSIONID + " != ?",
          new String[] { sessionID });
```

Comment: This appears to be deleting all from the database. I want to be able to keep only the one sessionID that is generated in the code from result

Comment: Is the session ID actually such a 36-character string?

Comment: yes, its coming from a WebService that autogenerates that sessionID. When a user logs in it generates a new sessionID

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create Helper method that delete unwanted sessionID from the DB.
- Create another Helper method that insert new SessionID
- Call Method that deletes previous sessionID first follow by method that Insert new One.